Ubuntu 24.04 with Nvidia driver is not working
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, my external monitor stopped working. I have an NVIDIA graphics card, the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, and I installed NVIDIA driver version 560.35.03. My output from the nvidia-smi command is shown.

I have tried multiple versions of drivers (535, 550, 555, and 470), but nothing works.
I tried completely removing the NVIDIA driver multiple times with sudo apt-get remove --purge *nvidia* and reinstalling it with a clean installation.
My kernel version is updated to 6.8.0-44-generic.
Secure boot is DISABLED too.
prime-select is set to the nvidia option.
When I run the command for Ubuntu drivers, I get the output: udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead., however all drivers show up afterwards. This message appears x times, where x equals the number of available NVIDIA drivers.

output for xrand --listproviders is below
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

See launchpad bug 2037004 for the ubuntu-drivers/Soft&Updates driver list problem.  The 560 might only be in the graphics drivers PPA -- did you install the drivers driectly (e.g. apt install nvidia-driver-xxx)?  Are you running xorg or wayland?  If xorg, please add the output of xrandr --listproviders to your original posting.

First, I installed it using ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, which installed version 560 by default. Later, I manually installed the driver using the command you mentioned, for versions 550 and 555, but it didn't work as well. I use xorg. I have added the output to the original.

If nothing will work I will probably install Ubuntu 22.04, which works perfectly.

Switch to nouveau driver, then purge all the packages with nvidia in their name: sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia. Delete any file with nvidia in the name in /etc/modprobe.d.  Now try the 560 install from ubuntu-drivers or Software&Updates/Additional Drivers. I'm using 560-open on a 3080 on Ubuntu 24.04 desktop on external monior without problems.

Thank you. I tried what you suggested: applied the nouveau driver, restarted, purged all NVIDIA drivers with autoclean and autoremove, cleaned modprobe.d from any NVIDIA files, restarted again, and finally installed 550-open/555-open/560-open, but it's still not working :/. I will roll back to 22.04 and wait a little longer for this version. These versions were installed separately using the same process after they failed to work.

You need to go "Start >> Preferences >> Additional Drivers"
You suppose to see the list of nvidia drivers.
Moreover go " Start >> Preference >> Nvidia X Server Settings"
Check the PRIME Profiles section.

Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I tried to install the mentioned versions of the Nvidia driver through 'Additional Drivers,' but how could that help me? In Nvidia settings, I have already set it to Nvidia (Performance Mode).

Start >> Preference >> Nvidia X Server Settings >> X Server Display Configuration >> Detect Display

I used xrandr for this, but no displays were detected. Cause I dont have any option in nvidia settings like "X server Display configuration"

Try Disconnecting and Reconnecting the monitor while the PC is off and restart.

yes, this was first thing which I did, restart and reconnecting it multiple times

try changing  Start >> Preference >> Nvidia X Server Settings"
Check the PRIME Profiles section. to Nvidia On Demand.,

prime select is setup to Nvidia

When you go to BIOS test is the screen detected?

There is no problem with the detection of the monitor. I have dual boot, and when I boot into Windows, there is no issue.

I would suggest you to reinstall Ubuntu without Nvidia drivers.
Then try using the appropriate driver after consulting with Nvidia.

Try the following. Go to Nvidia X Server Settings >> PRIME Profiles And change the option from NVIDIA On-Demand to NVIDIA (Performance Mode).
Then Under your GPU go to PowerMizer and under PowerMizer SEttings, change Preferred Mode to Auto.
